# Indicating country of manufacture with Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

I'm adding Rich Snippets to a Washington DC area furniture store's website. Nearly all the manufacturers they carry manufacture in the USA and with the push to buy Made in America, I want to ensure that info gets picked up by search bots and in local ads placed on search engines.

I'm drawing a blank looking for a property that declares country of manufacture. Am I just missing it, or did they leave something so important out of the vocabulary?

NOTE: Just stating the country code of a manufacturer says NOTHING about where they actually manufacture their products. Many corporations are in the USA but all their products are made offshore.

Answer (score 0):

I think Schema.org doesn’t define a suitable property.

It would most likely be defined for [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product), but the only related property is [`manufacturer`](http://schema.org/manufacturer), which, as you described, doesn’t do the job. The only current solution would be to make use of [`additionalProperty`](http://schema.org/additionalProperty), but it’s probably not that useful without a standardized [`propertyID`](http://schema.org/propertyID).

You could suggest that Schema.org should add such a property:
https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues

Comment: I believe you are right. I will definitely start a push on GitHub to include a suitable itemProp in Schema.org/Product.